# HaProxy - 502 Bad Gateway : HTTP spoken on HTTPS port

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, haproxy

I'll try to explain my issue.

I'm working on HaProxy 1.5.8 / apache 2.2, and I try to do some SSL configuration, but I fail, and fail, and fail.

Let's see some logs:

**Haproxy Logs**

```
Aug 13 17:00:28 localhost haproxy[10930]: x.x.x.x - - [13/Aug/2015:15:00:28 +0000] "URLxxxxx HTTP/1.1" 502 +656 "" "" 50567 131 "FT-https-in~" "BK-https-out" "myserver-https" 13 0 1 -1 +17 PH-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" ""
```

**Apache Error Logs**

```
[Thu Aug 13 17:02:38 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
[Thu Aug 13 17:02:38 2015] [info] [client haproxy-server] SSL handshake failed: HTTP spoken on HTTPS port; trying to send HTML error page
[Thu Aug 13 17:02:38 2015] [info] SSL Library Error: 336027804 error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request speaking HTTP to HTTPS port!?
```

My HaProxy configuration :

```
# - Frontend - HTTPS in
frontend FT-https-in
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/my_cert.pem
log global
option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
option httplog clf
option log-separate-errors
option logasap
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
default_backend BK-https-out


# - Backend - HTTPS out
backend BK-https-out
mode http
option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1/8 header X-Forwarded-For
log global
option httplog clf
option tcplog
option http-pretend-keepalive
option http-server-close
# pool de serveur du backend
server myserver-https x.x.x.x:443 check
```

I tried to fix my issue with headers configuration like :

```
 http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
 http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
 http-request add-header X-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
 http-request set-header X-SSL %[ssl_fc]
```

My pem file is build like this : crt / key / bundle

But issue still here.
If someone could have an idea to help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to tell HAproxy that the backend server is using SSL:

```
server myserver-https x.x.x.x:443 ssl check verify none
```

The 'verify none' part tells haproxy not to verify the certificate chain.  I've included it, but it may not be necessary.

You shouldn't need any of the header lines you indicated unless you want them.

Comment: Thank you! I spent the better half of my day trying to troubleshoot this.